# Задача «Переставить min и max»

Tags: python, list

> Условие.
>   В списке все элементы различны. Поменяйте местами минимальный и максимальный элемент этого списка.

```py
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
a[a.index(max(a))], a[a.index(min(a))] = a[a.index(min(a))], a[a.index(max(a))]
print(' '.join([str(i) for i in a]))
```

В одних примерах программа работает, в других просто выдаёт изначальный список. Например: на списке `3 4 5 2 1` не работает, а на списке `1 5 4 3 2` работает.

Answer (score 1):

Немного переписал ваш код, но смысл такой же:

```
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
min_index = a.index(min(a))
max_index = a.index(max(a))
[a[max_index], a[min_index]] = [a[min_index], a[max_index]]
print(' '.join([str(i) for i in a]))
```

Comment: спасибо, но вопрос был больше, в том чтобы понять почему программа с этими методами не работает, хотя всё логически должно работать.

Comment: Я немного разбираюсь в python проблема была в a[a.index(min(a))] и a[a.index(max(a))], но я не понимаю почему он барахлит, вот по этому лучше писать все по порядку :D